# Two column document, 2X1 figure placement

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, align, two-column

I need to place 3 figures in a two-column document, `wherein the 3rd figure at the bottom needs to be centred!` How can I do this?

I want something like this:

[image]

To do the same for 4 figures I have been using:

```
\begin{figure*} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1.eps}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2.eps}\par 
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3.eps}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.eps}
\end{multicols}
\caption{Here}
\end{figure*}
```

which works perfectly and I am able to get 4 figures aligned in the two-column document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering 
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}\quad
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}\par\medskip
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-c}
\caption{a figure with three subfigures}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Instead of manually specifying the height, is there an automatic way like `width=\linewidth` that I can use for the 3 figures?

Comment: @ThePredator You're welcome. I only specified the height for my example. You could use a fraction of `\linewidth`, as in `width=.45\linewidth` and change `\quad` to `\hfill`, for example.